# Java - setting password from file in GUI

Tags: java, swing, file-io, passwords, jframe

I've recently learned how to use the NetBeans GUI editor and I'm really liking it, but I've run across a problem. I'm making a program for personal use that requires a login. The password for the login is retrieved from a file and can be changed. So far, making the text file, putting contents and changing contents is not the issue. My issue is setting the String password to equal whatever is in the text file. Please help me out. Here is the code. (jPasswordField1 is the password box and jButton1 is the button to open menus to change password.)

```
package my.shortcutApp;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class shotcutApp extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    File passwordFile = new File("C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/userdata/193530500/7/remote/Game Data.txt");
    String password; // I need this to equal ^^
    String reset = "";
    public shotcutApp()
    {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        loginPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        loginPanel.setName("Organizer"); // NOI18N

        jPasswordField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jPasswordField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Login");

        jButton1.setText("change");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout loginPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(loginPanel);
        loginPanel.setLayout(loginPanelLayout);
        loginPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            loginPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(loginPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(128, 128, 128)
                .addGroup(loginPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(loginPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 171, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(128, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        loginPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            loginPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, loginPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(259, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(loginPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPasswordField1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(loginPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(loginPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jPasswordField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        String input = evt.getActionCommand();
        if (input.equals(password))
        {
            loginPanel.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if (!input.equals(password))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Wrong password.");
        }
        jPasswordField1.setText("");
    }                                               

    @SuppressWarnings("ConvertToTryWithResources")
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        if (!passwordFile.exists())
        {
            reset = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter new password.");
            try {passwordFile.createNewFile();} catch (IOException ex) {Logger.getLogger(shotcutApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
            try {
                BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(passwordFile));
                output.write(reset);
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(shotcutApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        else if (passwordFile.exists())
        {
            reset = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter old password.");
            if (reset.equals(password))
            {
                try {PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(passwordFile);pw.close();} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {Logger.getLogger(shotcutApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
                password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter new password.");
                try {
                    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(passwordFile));
                    output.write(password);
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(shotcutApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            else if (!reset.equals(password))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Wrong password.");
            }
        }
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(shotcutApp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(shotcutApp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(shotcutApp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(shotcutApp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new shotcutApp().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel loginPanel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: My issue is setting the String password to equal whatever is in the text file. what do you mean by this? plz post up your file content too

Comment: Do you know how to read from a file in Java?

Comment: *"I'm making a program for personal use that requires a login."*  1) If it were for personal use I'd hard code the password. 2) If it is *actually* for use by others, it would be inadvisable to store passwords in text files.  3) If this is an arbitrary assignment for learning a bit about Java I/O I'd just ..say so.

Answer (score 0):

if i did understood you correctly you need actually a configuration file and read-write properties from it. I have make one for you please see. I made  the password in textfield to show you what is going on , you can later change it to passwordfield. You can also open configuration file and make changes and save.You can give whatever name you want to your configuration file. You can change the password as much as you can when you enter the new ones and press save button and then the  configuration file will be updated.

**Configuration File**

[image]

[image]

**Create Class Configs**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Configs {

    public static Properties prop = new Properties();

    public void SaveProp(String title, String value) {

        try {
            prop.setProperty(title, value);
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream("configuration.con"), null);

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }

    public String GetProp(String title) {
        String value = "";

        try {

            prop.load(new FileInputStream("configuration.con"));
            value = prop.getProperty(title);

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        return value;
    }

}
```

**Your Fields in Login Class**

```
Configs con = new Configs();
String UserName = "UserName";
String Password = "Password";
String newpassword;
String newuser;
```

**Save Button Action Performed**

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    con.SaveProp(UserName, jTextField1.getText());
    con.SaveProp(Password, jTextField2.getText());

}
```

**Display Button Action Performed**

```
      private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

      newuser = con.GetProp("UserName");
      newpassword = con.GetProp("Password");
      jTextField3.setText(newuser);
      jTextField4.setText(newpassword);

}
```